# Codeigniter email being blocked by with yahoo domains

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, hosting

Hi I have a problem with my script sending emails out. Basically my script sends an email out like this:

From: zyz@yahoo.com
to: order@abc.ca

Even though the script is being sent out from @abc domain (Similiar to how gmail users send yahoo emails out from their account).

I get this message back from my server log:

```
550-5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from yahoo.com is not accepted due to domain's 550-5.7.1 DMARC policy.
```

Is there a way to bypass this with $config settings? Using a different smtp outgoing server?

Here is my email code:

```
$config['wordwrap'] = FALSE;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html'; 


$this->email->initialize($config);  

 $a=$this->load->view('cart/email',$data,true);
$this->email->from($data['email'], $data['fname'].' '.$data['lname']);
$this->email->to('order@abc.ca'); 
$this->email->subject('Your Order');
$this->email->message($a);  
$this->email->send();
  echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider adding an SPF record with your domain name provider.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework

Answer (score 0):

Your mail server neither conforms to Yahoo's [DKIM](http://www.dkim.org/) nor is listed in the [SPF](http://www.openspf.org/) record for yahoo.com, so the receiving mail server does not accept your message.

Your options to fix this include:

- get Yahoo to add your IP to the SPF record (not likely)
- have your server use your credentials to send the mail through Yahoo's outbound mail server https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120221123159AAYqXz1
- use a from address in a domain that does not use SPF/DKIM
- use a from address in the @abc domain and use the abc domain outbound mail server